# Prove: minimal origin-to-ellipse $|z+a|+|z-a|=2r$ lies on minor axis, using complex numbers

Tags: inequality, optimization, complex-numbers, conic-sections, problem-solving

Let $|z+a|+|z-a|=2r$ where $a,z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r>|a|$.

> Prove the minimum of $|z|$ is $\sqrt{r^2-|a|^2}$

The equation describes an ellipse, and it's clear from drawing a picture that the minimal $|z|$ are the two vertices of the ellipse on the minor axis. How can we **prove this claim analytically using complex numbers**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the axis going through $a$ and $-a$ also goes through the origin,  and is all real multiples of $a.$  The other axis is real multiples of $ia$

Comment: @WillJagy That's right, it's the major axis and $|z|$ -max lies here, following the triangle inequality. But how about minimizing $|z|$, is there a reason, why the minimum should lie on the axis perpendicular to axis of maximum?

Comment: of course. draw some pictures.

Comment: @WillJagy I am not sure though how to prove it from the rules of complex number

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the example I made up is correct: all the important points have integer real and imaginary parts. Draw $a = 20 + 15i$  and $r=65$

Comment: I am not sure how this example shows how to prove it from the rules of complex numbers, can you give a more explicit hint, maybe? tks!

Comment: @ago752 no. I want you to get a piece of paper and draw the situation, so I have supplied something where the first several points involved have integer real and imaginary parts, and the distances are integers. If you refuse to do that, I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

$|z+a|+|z-a|=2r$ is equation of an ellipse with foci at $-a$ and $a.$
Focal distance is $|2a|$ and the length of one axis is $2r.$ Thus the other axis has length $$2|d|=2\sqrt{r^2-|a|^2}.$$
Since the axes of ellipse are perpendicular, extremal points (vertices) lying on this axis are $$\pm d=\pm i\times |d|\times {a\over |a|}.$$
The nearest points to the origin are vertices of the ellipse that lie on the minor axis.

- If $|a|<\sqrt{r^2-|a|^2},$ then $z_{1,2}=\pm a.$
- If $|a|>\sqrt{r^2-|a|^2},$ then $z_{1,2}=\pm d.$

Comment: What you call $\arg a$ would normally be denoted $\exp(i\arg a)$ or $a/|a|$.

Comment: @J.G. thanks, edited.